# using IUP - Is there any way to clear all the content out of a IupText object?

Tags: iup

using IUP - Is there any way to clear all the content out of a IupText object?  I'm implementing a very simple 4 line display that is supposed to emulate a hardware device.  Unfortunately, through days of experimentation, I found that using IupInsert eventually reaches a limit, so you need to delete the contents.  The only way I was able to simulate this was to destroy the IupText object and the IupDialog object containing it.  This is very inefficient and ugly, but the documentation is misleading.  I also attempted to detach and destroy the text box, without destroying the dialog, but I was unable to insert/append a new text box that would actually show up on the screen.  The return value from the append was valid, but even after refresh, IupShow, etc., the dlg would never display the text again.  Thank you for any insights

Answer (score 0):

Just set the VALUE attribute to "".